# Android: get access to view elements in OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have a Fragment container and some buttons outside the fragment which interact with the content of the fragment. When I click on the button, I need to get the information inside the text elements. This is what I have right now, but it doesn't work.
The code comes from the fragment pager demos.

```
Button bm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
bm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editTextIn1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextIn1);
  }
});
```

edit
I use this sample:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

public class FragmentStatePagerSupport extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 10;

    MyAdapter mAdapter;

    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_first);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_last);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(NUM_ITEMS-1);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
        int mNum;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
         * as an argument.
         */
        static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
            ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cheeses.sCheeseStrings));
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what "text element" are you talking about?

Comment: for example the EditText editTextIn1 which is lying inside the Fragment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The v in your onCLickListener is referring to the Button itself, and calling findViewByID on the button means that the button is looking through its children (it doesn't have any) to find an EditText element.  if this code is running in an activity, you may be able to do:

```
Button bm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
bm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editTextIn1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIn1);
  }
});
```

alternately, if you have a reference to the fragment's container (like a framelayout or something), you can do

```
Button bm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
bm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editTextIn1 = (EditText) myFragmentContainer.findViewById(R.id.editTextIn1);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you. that makes it better but I still have problems. I have this Fragment thing, which always loads Elements in advance. So the editTextIn1 points to another than what is displayed. How do I get the correct view context for the code sample above?