# How to get information of an item with button in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, adapter

I need help with a project in Android where I'm working. I have an AsyncTask that external data collected through the internet with a custom adapter.

My view currently has a view that is generated by the adapter and outside of it, contains a button. I would like to press that button give me current information from view as for example the name of the element.

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ebebeb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Menú"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/openmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="Desc"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/love"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_love"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="Desc"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/love"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/love"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/love"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="Desc"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.unomasdelafamilia.sevilla.CardContainer
        android:id="@+id/layoutview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ebebeb" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infobtn"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lovebtn"
            android:background="@drawable/love" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.class**

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mCardContainer = (CardContainer) findViewById(R.id.layoutview);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Obteniendo datos ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
    return json;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    if(json != null){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String image = c.getString(imagen);
                adapter.add(new CardModel(id, "Sevilla", image));
            }

            mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Compruebe su conexión e inténtelo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //No hay datos 
    }

}
```

**CardModel.class**

```
public class CardModel {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    //private Drawable cardImageDrawable;
    private String image;
    /*  private Drawable cardLikeImageDrawable;
    private Drawable cardDislikeImageDrawable;*/

    private OnCardDimissedListener mOnCardDimissedListener = null;

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = null;

    public interface OnCardDimissedListener {
        void onLike();
        void onDislike();
    }

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void OnClickListener();
    }

    /*public CardModel(String string, Drawable drawable) {
        this(null, null, null);
    }*/

    public CardModel(String title, String description, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        //this.cardImageDrawable = cardImage;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public CardModel(String title, String description, Bitmap cardImage) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        //this.cardImageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(null, cardImage);
    }

    public CardModel(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /*public Drawable getCardLikeImageDrawable() {
        return cardLikeImageDrawable;
    }

    public void setCardLikeImageDrawable(Drawable cardLikeImageDrawable) {
        this.cardLikeImageDrawable = cardLikeImageDrawable;
    }

    public Drawable getCardDislikeImageDrawable() {
        return cardDislikeImageDrawable;
    }

    public void setCardDislikeImageDrawable(Drawable cardDislikeImageDrawable) {
        this.cardDislikeImageDrawable = cardDislikeImageDrawable;
    }
     */
/*  public void setOnCardDimissedListener( OnCardDimissedListener listener ) {
        this.mOnCardDimissedListener = listener;
    }

    public OnCardDimissedListener getOnCardDimissedListener() {
        return this.mOnCardDimissedListener;
    }


    public void setOnClickListener( OnClickListener listener ) {
        this.mOnClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {
        return this.mOnClickListener;
    }*/
}
```

**SimpleCardStackAdapter.java**

```
public final class SimpleCardStackAdapter extends CardStackAdapter {

    public SimpleCardStackAdapter(Context mContext) {
        super(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public View getCardView(int position, CardModel model, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.std_card_inner, parent, false);
            assert convertView != null;
        }

        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp_image);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

        //((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp_image)).setImageDrawable(model.getImage());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(model.getTitle());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(model.getDescription());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(model.getImage(), loader, image);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((ViewManager)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In short, how I can get ítem information when the button is pressed. Thank you very much to all, Greetings

Comment: What sort of item information? An id, string...?

Comment: Hi @AmmarCSE I need string

Comment: Yes, but is the string dynamic or statically assigned to each unique item?

Comment: Ah! the String assigned to each items are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags) property of views in Android.

So, you can dynamically set the tag like

```
String item = "item";
Button button = findViewById(R.id.Button);
button.setTag(item);
```

where and whenever is appropriate in you code.

Then, you can retrieve the tag when clicked like

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
       String myString = (String) button.getTag();
    }
```

**Update**
After understanding OPs requirement.

In your overridden `getCardView` handler, after you instantiate the `ImageView` like

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp_image);
```

set its tag from the model object like

```
image.setTag(model.getTitle());
```

then, in your click handler, get the tag of the ImageView like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View button) {
   ImageView image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sp_image);
   String item = (String)image.getTag();
}
```

Comment: It works! but why only shows me one item? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29764789/captura.png

Comment: @Adrian Well, you can only set one item per tag per button. If you only have one button, then in your code you can change the tag per your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand @AmmarCSE . You can post a short example please?

Comment: @Adrian, maybe I dont understand what you are trying to do. You say it only shows you one item. But you have only one button which is the lovebtn.

Comment: I have several item and a button. By clicking on the item, the item is removed and passed to the view a different item. And the button will always be visible. I just want to get information from the item That is currently showing view

Comment: Oh! I see. Then why not set the tag on the ImageView for each unique item. Then, when button is clicked, get the tag of the imageview instead. Let me know if you need help with a code example!

Comment: Thank you very much, you could make an example please?

Comment: I checked it and it tells me error: The method getView () is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener () {}

Comment: You will need to navigate to the ImageView with respect to the button. In your xml layout above, there is no ImageView with id sp_image. Where do you have this ImageView?

Comment: @Adrian Try changing getView().findViewById(R.id.sp_image) to just findViewById(R.id.sp_image)

Comment: My imageview is std_card_inner.xml, which is the template I use for the adapter

Comment: @Adrian, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261499/android-get-access-to-view-elements-in-onclicklistener

Comment: I've been tested and my result is the same. The result shown is the last element and not the current :(