# findViewById not finding views from relevant activity

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid, android-studio-3.0

**EDIT: Problem Solved after rebuilding the project.**

I am making a app which shares data between two activities.
Name of two Activites : 1. MainActivity 2.ScorerActivity

When I try to make instance of a TextView object int the ScorerActivity the findViewById method finds the id from the MainActivity layout. It does not find the view which is in the ScorerActivity layout.

MainActivity Java

```
package com.example.android.badmintonscorer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText player1Name = findViewById(R.id.player1_name);
            String player1 = player1Name.getText().toString();

            EditText player2Name = findViewById(R.id.player2_name);
            String player2 = player2Name.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScorerActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("player1_name", player1);
            intent.putExtra("player2_name", player2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

MainActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.example.android.badmintonscorer.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player1_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Name of Player 1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player2_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Name of Player 2"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

ScorerActivity Java

```
package com.example.android.badmintonscorer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScorerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scorer);

    TextView player1 = findViewById(R.id.p1name); //Cannot resolve symbol
}
}
```

ScorerActivity layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00f921"
tools:context="com.example.android.badmintonscorer.ScorerActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p1name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Player 1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p1score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/p1plus1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f9bf00"
            android:onClick="pointp1"
            android:text="+1 Point" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/p1df"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f9bf00"
            android:onClick="dfp1"
            android:text="Double Fault" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p2name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Player 2"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p2score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/p2plus1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f9bf00"
            android:onClick="pointp2"
            android:text="+1 Point" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/p2df"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f9bf00"
            android:onClick="dfp2"
            android:text="Double Fault" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:background="#f9bf00"
    android:text="Reset" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#f9bf00"
    android:text="Finish" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:background="#f9bf00"
    android:text="Share" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please update your question with the error message that you are getting.

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261558/7052400

Comment: try to cast in textview. clean and rebuild  the project. and try to restart android studio. hope it helps

Comment: Try to rebuild/clean project. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
package com.example.android.badmintonscorer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ScorerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scorer);

        TextView player1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.p1name);
    }
    }
```

clean project and rebuild code.

Comment: Answers providing just block of code w/o any explanation why it is expected to fix OP's problem nor mentioning what is done differently are pretty useless from educational point of view, which SO is also trying to provide. Please consider making your answer useful by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the method `findViewById` returns a `View` object and therefore it should be casted to its appropriate subclasses for example assigning a Button will be like:

```
Button yourButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
```

Notice the casting here  `(Button) findViewById(...`
So go on change all your Views and cast them to their respective Subclasses. like how you can see below:
MainActivity.java

```
 Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_button);
 final EditText player1Name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1_name);
 final EditText player2Name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2_name);
 startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String player1 = player1Name.getText().toString();
        String player2 = player2Name.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScorerActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("player1_name", player1);
        intent.putExtra("player2_name", player2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 });
}
```

ScorerActivity.Java

```
public class ScorerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scorer);
        TextView player1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.p1name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers providing just block of code w/o any explanation why it is expected to fix OP's problem nor mentioning what is done differently are pretty useless from educational point of view, which SO is also trying to provide. Please consider making your answer useful by editing it.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski  ok next time i take care of it.